# Use cached webview resource when showing a new fragment?

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

Suppose you have a list of articles in a webview.

When a user click an article, you want to show it on a new activity.
Because you have all the data already, you don't need to contact server to show the article.

What's good way to show the detail article in a webview without accessing network?

Comment: For that you need to pass data from web view to activity.

Comment: I can pass whatever data (JSON) to new activity, what I can't figure out is how do I make the new webview in the new activity to use the json and resources (javascript/css..) downloaded in the list activity?